# QR Application in Python

Tags: python, django, qr-code

I want to create Django application. The logic is next: I scan the QR-code using QR- scanner, and then send this code to the web app. After that the app connect with Data Base and regarding to this information display some information.   Could you give advice how to start this project, maybe some examples? i don't understand how looks the process of sending qr code from Qr scanner to app.

Answer (score 1):

You must know that QRscanner scan QRcodes of any of your products for example and then it hash this QRcode after reading it into text, this text is what you need.So, what you need is to set focus maybe on a textbox on your website and scan QR code.Second, on textchange event you take this text and save it to database.Third, you can get it back or apply any action or event on your website

Best

Comment: Thanks a lot. But in case if I need automatically send this text into web app immediately after scanning, how generally can look this process (from QR-scaner to my app) ?

Comment: you can create a background service and always listen to an input from your QRcode scanner so whenever you scan a QRcode it re-direct it maybe through http request to your website